# How do I calculate average for 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, average

I wanted to know whether the calculation for average in 2D arrays is the same as 1D arrays? Can I also see a java code for it? This is what I have but I am not getting the correct answer.

```java
static int avgRecursion(int a[][], int i, int j, int f) {
    // Last element
    if (i == f - 1)
        return a[i][j];

    // When index is 0, divide sum computed so far by n.
    if (i == 0)
        return ((a[i][j] + avgRecursion(a, i + 1, j, f)) / f);

    // Compute sum
    return (a[i][j] + avgRecursion(a, i + 1, j, f));
}

static int[][] array;

static {
    array = new int[3][4];

    System.out.println("Enter 12 numbers: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            array[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
    int f = array.length;
    int average = avgRecursion(array, 0, 0, f);
    System.out.println("The average of the 2D array: " + average);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? I'm not sure what you're asking for since an "average over a 2D array" doesn't really make a whole lot of sense. An `average` function takes in some collection of integers and returns a single value. However, you can get an average for a _flattened_ 2D array, or get multiple averages along one of the dimensions, returning a 1D array of averages. In any case, we need more clarification; examples would help.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you want to find the average of all the values stored in the 2D array. Here's a small program for that:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = new int[4][5];
    int sum = 0;
    // Length * Breadth gives total number of elements in array
    int arrLength = (arr.length * arr[0].length);

    // Populate array
    // Your program gets the values from the user
    // but i'm hardcoding them. Hope you get the point
    for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < arr[row].length; col++) {
            arr[row][col] = 20;
        }
    }

    // Actual answer starts here
    // Calculate sum of all values stored in the array
    for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < arr[row].length; col++) {
            sum += arr[row][col];
        }
    }

    // Print total sum / length of array
    System.out.print("The average of the 2D array is " + sum / arrLength);
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly ... recursion isn't necessary, just two nested loops.

Comment: I was asked to use recursion. Is it possible to show an example of a code for that?

Comment: There's nothing about a 2D array that would make recursion better. You could replace each loop with a recursive function, if you're doing an exercise to teach recursion (the second "loop" would be within the first recursive function, in that case).

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten the 2D array to one dimension and take the average of the 1D array as usual:

```java
int[][] arr = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}, {9}};

double avg = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
        .average()
        .orElse(Double.NaN);

System.out.println(avg); // 5.0
```